# Running the following query in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to run a query as follows in Symfony:

```
SELECT * FROM company 
WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE '$search%'  THEN 1        
              WHEN name LIKE '%$search'  THEN 2      
              WHEN name LIKE '%$search%' THEN 3 
END
LIMIT 0,10
```

There seems to be a lot of the limitations with `createQuery()` and `findBy()` I was wondering if there was a way to query the DB in such a way with Symfony2?

Note, the company table is also set up as an entity.

This is what I tried which doesn't accomplish my whole query:

```
$this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('testMyBundle:Company') 
   ->findBy(array(),array(),10,($current-1)*$numItemsPerPage);
```

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't like solutions like that, but should working:

```
// CompanyRepository.php
public function getSth() {
    $query = 'your sql query here';
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

And in your controller:

```
$this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('testMyBundle:Company')->getSth();
```

Comment: +1, Thank you, I appreciate the help. Is there a particular reason you don't like solutions like this? it seems to be working great! :)

Comment: I don't like to execute raw sql queries. This can cause problems during refactoring. So, please use it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) should work:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT c
        FROM testMyBundle:Company c
        WHERE c.name LIKE :search
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN c.name LIKE :search  THEN 1
        WHEN c.name LIKE :search  THEN 2
        WHEN c.name LIKE :search THEN 3
        END
    ')
    ->setParameter('search', '%search%')
    ->setMaxResults(10)
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->execute()
;
```